# Setting UTC timezone with numeric values in JS [UTC+2, UTC+3, UTC-12, etc]

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, timezone-offset, moment-timezone

How can I create a date with a specific timezone like that [UTC+2, UTC+3, UTC-12, etc] but not with string like that 'America/New York' in js/moment.js? I have a list of all timezones from server in this format [UTC+2, UTC+3, UTC-12, etc], so I need to create dates with a choosen timezone. I tried to use moment.js but it accepts only strings formate. Thanks ahed!

Comment: those aren't timezones. those are utc offsets which timezones change which one they use

Comment: Any way I need to create a date with these offsets)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Yogi: I always hesitate using a more than 10 years old answer as a duplicate. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to use moment.js but...

Didn't you come accross those methods: [.utc()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/), [.add()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) and [.format()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) ?

### EDIT

To accomodate non-full hour offsets, you can use [.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to retreive the sign *(+ or -)* of the offset, the hour and the optionnal minute.

Here is the actual possible offsets list: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_offsets#UTC+05:45,_E*)

It outputs UTC time if your offset only is `UTC` or is an empty string.

```js
const timeOffsets = ["UTC+2", "UTC+3", "UTC-12", "UTC+5:45", "UTC-3:30", "UTC", ""]

function getlocalTime(offset) {
  const time = offset.match(/([\+\-])(\d{1,2}):?(\d{2})?/)
  let sign = ""
  let numericOffset = 0
  if (time) {
    sign = time[1]
    numericOffset = parseInt(time[2]) + (time[3] ? parseInt(time[3]) / 60 : 0)
  }

  return moment().utc().add(sign + numericOffset, "hours").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
}

const result = timeOffsets.map(getlocalTime)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but wasn't shure. I thought that may be there was already a ready-made solution in moment.js. I guess it's what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Consider accepting the answer (green check mark) ;)

Comment: This answer only accommodates whole hour offsets. There are many half hour offsets such as India +5:30, South Australia +9:30, Lord Howe Island +10:30 and so on.

Comment: @RobG: Thanks for the PR ;) - I improved it.

Comment: Cool. BTW, the wikipedia link seems to be for current offsets. Prior to around 1900 offsets were generally for each place based on local mean solar noon, so were like "Wed Jan 01 1800 00:00:00 GMT-1421 (ChST)". Some included seconds. It was only when railways allowed fast travel over long distances that timezones were introduced to standardise offsets and make time comparisons between different places when using timetables and schedules easier. ;-)